# Don't delete Foreign key even if primary key is deleted

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have 1 table **Person** with id (primary key) and name. And another table **items** which contains id (primary key), person_id (foreign key) references person (id), item name etc.

I want to add constraint like if I delete 1 row from Person table then items table's row should not be deleted and don't set null to person_id field.

Answer (score 0):

Disable referential integrity.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/primary-and-foreign-key-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15